# How to install colortheme in NeoVim in Mac OS X?

Tags: macvim, neovim

I just installed NeoVim VimR 0.13.1 from https://github.com/qvacua/vimr/releases
for Mac OSX. I was able to set default options by creating a file at

```
~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

Now I am having a hard time trying use a color theme. For example I am interested with OceanicNext theme from https://github.com/mhartington/oceanic-next

So I downloaded the zip file, unzipped it then it creates a folder called

```
oceanic-next-master
```

So I moved this folder to

```
~/.config/nvim/oceanic-next-master
```

Added necessary code to the init.vim file

```
" For Neovim 0.1.3 and 0.1.4
let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1

" Or if you have Neovim >= 0.1.5
if (has("termguicolors"))
 set termguicolors
endif

" Theme
syntax enable
colorscheme OceanicNext
```

But even restarting the VimR, nothing happens. So I tried renaming the folder name from

```
~/.config/nvim/oceanic-next-master
```

to

```
~/.config/nvim/OceanicNext
```

Still no luck. So tried to copy the actual OceanicNext.vim file to

```
~/.config/nvim/OceanicNext.vim
```

Still didn't work restarting it. So I tried running the command directly

```
colorscheme OceanicNext
```

But it give me the following error message

```
Cannot find color scheme 'OceanicNext'
```

I also tried install other color scheme from https://github.com/frankier/neovim-colors-solarized-truecolor-only but still wasn't able to make it work.

I also have MacVim installed and just copy and pasting the plugins into the ~/.vim worked, but looks like NeoVim is different? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The nvim documentation on the colorscheme command `:help colorscheme`

> :colo[rscheme] {name}
>
> Load color scheme {name}. This searches 'runtimepath' for the file
> "colors/{name}.vim". The first one that is found is loaded. Also
> searches all plugins in 'packpath', first below "start" and then under
> "opt".

You can put the color scheme file into `~/.config/nvim/colors` f older. Where `~` is your user home directory.

Consider you have "nord.vim" colorscheme. The full path to it will be `~/.config/nvim/colors/nord.vim`.

Then the `:colorscheme nord` command will be able to load the theme.

By the way, [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugin is great for managing vim and neovim plugins and colorschemes. It will install/update/delete plugins including colorschemes for you. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Had to install vim-plug manager from https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug
by placing the plug.vim file to

```
~/.config/nvim/autoload
```

to install the plugins.